# Swift, Continue recording after interruption

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am trying to allow the user to record audio for long duration.

So what am trying to achieve?

- Start recording will stop any other media like music
- If the AVAudioRecorder gets interrupted, it pauses.
- When the interruption ended, or the user resume the recording manually the AVAudioRecorder stops any other media and  resumes and continue recording.

My problem is when the AVAudioRecorder gets interrupted and resumed few times, it loses the recoded data, for example if I recorded for 30 seconds when I play it back, its duration becomes 10 seconds.
Amazingly, this happen only when it get's interrupted, but if the user pauses and resumes the recoding many times, no problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
func startRecording() {
        if !audioRecord!.recording {
            do {
                secondCounter = 0
                try self.audioSession?.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
                try self.audioSession?.setActive(true)
                self.stopAudioPlayer()
                self.playButton.enabled = false
                self.playButtonInPlayingMode(false)
                self.hideAudioContainer(true)
                audioRecord?.prepareToRecord()
                audioRecord?.meteringEnabled = true
                audioRecord!.record()
                self.micButton.tag = recording_state;
                self.monitorRecoderTime()
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }

    func pauseRecording() {
        if audioRecord != nil && audioRecord!.recording {
            self.recordingPauseMode()
            audioRecord?.pause()
        }
    }

    func recordingPauseMode() {
        self.micButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "micro.png"), forState: .Normal);
        self.micButton.tag = pause_state;
        self.stopMonitoring()
    }

    func resumeRecoding() {
        if audioRecord != nil && !audioRecord!.recording {
            self.micButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "micro_filled.png"), forState: .Normal);
            self.micButton.tag = recording_state;
            if audioRecord!.record() {
                print("Recording Resumed")
            }else{
                print("Unable to resume recording")
            }
            self.monitorRecoderTime()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm looking into this as well. What I can tell you is that calling `record()` might be part of the issue. Calling `record()` method implicitly calls prepareToRecord(), which creates (or erases) an audio file and prepares the system for recording.